# Regex and pandas to read forecast sky condition string

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, regex, pandas

DataFrame methods to parse the sky condition from a terminal aerodrome forecast.

A line in a taf can report zero-eight cloud layers.  Cloud layers are required in predominate lines, and optional in temporary ones.  Cloud cover `SKC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC` is associated to an octave value.  `1, 3, 5, 8` as the min sky coverage for reporting a layer.

I struggled to find a pure regex solution to generate the the pattern I needed for repeating capture groups.  Hence the `_unpack_setup` function

```py
from typing import Iterable
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

TAF = """
KGCC 282320Z 2900/2924 09010KT P6SM -SHRA BKN070 OVC250
  FM290300 24011KT P6SM OVC040
  TEMPO 2903/2906 4SM -SHRA FEW010 FEW015 BKN020TCU OVC025
  FM291000 18009KT 3SM -TSRA BR OVC004CB
  FM291900 31022G33KT 6SM -SHRA OVC011
"""

OCTAVE_INDEX = pd.Series(
    (np.inf, 1, 3, 5, 8, np.nan), index=["SKC", "FEW", "SCT", "BKN", "OVC", np.nan]
)


def _unpack_setup():

    base = r"(SKC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC)(\d{3})?(CB|TCU)?\s?"
    layers = f"(?:{base})?" * 7
    columns = pd.Series(["CloudCover", "CloudBase", "Flags"])

    return (
        re.compile(base + layers, re.VERBOSE),
        pd.concat(columns + str(i) for i in range(1, 9)),
    )


celestial_dome, cloud_columns = _unpack_setup()


def unpack_index(index: pd.Index, *args: str) -> Iterable[pd.Index]:
    for col in args:
        yield index[index.str.contains(col)]


def octave(sky_coverage: pd.Series) -> np.ndarray:
    """octave indexer"""
    return OCTAVE_INDEX[sky_coverage].values


def get_sky_condition():
    """creates sky condtion dataframe"""
    series = pd.Series(re.split(r"(?:\s(?=BECMG|TEMPO|FM))", TAF.strip())).str.strip()

    sky_condition: pd.DataFrame = (
        series.str.extract(celestial_dome)
        .set_axis(cloud_columns, axis=1)
        .dropna(axis=1, how="all")
    )

    column_base, column_cover = unpack_index(
        sky_condition.columns, "CloudBase", "CloudCover"
    )

    sky_condition[column_base] = sky_condition[column_base].astype(float) * 100

    sky_condition[column_cover] = sky_condition[column_cover].apply(octave)
    print(sky_condition)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_sky_condition()
```

### results

```
   CloudCover1  CloudBase1 Flags1  CloudCover2  CloudBase2  CloudCover3  CloudBase3 Flags3  CloudCover4  CloudBase4
0          5.0      7000.0    NaN          8.0     25000.0          NaN         NaN    NaN          NaN         NaN
1          8.0      4000.0    NaN          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN    NaN          NaN         NaN
2          2.0      1000.0    NaN          2.0      1500.0          5.0      2000.0    TCU          8.0      2500.0
3          8.0       400.0     CB          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN    NaN          NaN         NaN
4          8.0      1100.0    NaN          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN    NaN          NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Is this sample even TAF-compliant? Your TEMPO line is missing a wind speed.

Comment: TEMPO lines do not require every parameter.  for example you could have a TEMPO condition of just `TEMPO 2903/2906 5000 TSRA`

Comment: If 5000 is a wind speed, that's missing `KT`. Otherwise, what is it?

Comment: visibility, 5000 meters

Comment: format is `group_type valid_period wind visibility present_weather cloud_cover pressure`.

Comment: the first line in a taf contains the `meta` data like the station_id, and valid_period of the forecast.  The last line will often contain the max and min temperatures for the period with `(?<=\s)(?:TX)?(?P<max_temp>-?\d{2})/(?P<max_temp_time>\d{4})Z?\s(?:TN)?(?P<min_temp>-?\d{2})/(?P<min_temp_time>\d{4})Z?`

Comment: Oh I see where the `5000` may have been confusing as the example uses statue miles for visibility and I used a meter example.  In the application I'm developing all values get converted to a standard unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of `get_sky_condition()`, I don't see why you do a `.str.strip()` when defining `series`:

> ```
> series = pd.Series(re.split(r"(?:\s(?=BECMG|TEMPO|FM))", TAF.strip())).str.strip()
> ```

I think that this should suffice?

```
series = pd.Series(re.split(r"(?:\s(?=BECMG|TEMPO|FM))", TAF.strip()))
```

---

For the regular expression, you could take advantage of named capture groups to avoid having to call `.set_axis(cloud_columns, axis=1)` to name the columns.

```
def cloud_layers_re() -> re:
    layer_re_fmt = \
        r"(?P<CloudCover{0}>SKC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC)" \
        r"(?P<CloudBase{0}>\d{{3}})?" \
        r"(?P<Flags{0}>CB|TCU)?"
    return re.compile(
        layer_re_fmt.format(1) +
        "".join("(?:\s+" + layer_re_fmt.format(i) + ")?" for i in range(2, 9))
    )

⋮

def get_sky_condition():
    """creates sky condtion dataframe"""
    series = pd.Series(re.split(r"(?:\s(?=BECMG|TEMPO|FM))", TAF.strip()))

    sky_condition: pd.DataFrame = (
        series.str.extract(cloud_layers_re())
        .dropna(axis=1, how="all")
    )

⋮
```

---

Since `get_sky_condition()` is named like a getter function, I'd expect that it returns its result rather than printing it.

Answer (score 1):

You've landed in trouble with your indices again. I think the shape of your dataframe significantly mischaracterises what your data are *actually* saying:

- Per station,
- per station observation time,
- per time group, there is some weather.

In addition to the above, per *altitude*, there are some clouds.

Whenever you say "per", there should be a `MultiIndex` level. Do not write `CloudCover1`, `CloudCover2` etc. columns. A two-stage `extract` can do this for you. There will be two separate dataframes because there are two different cardinalities. Said another way, the number of visibility measurements is very different from the number of cloud measurements, and to mash them into the same dataframe does not make sense and is de-normalised, in database speak. The two separate dataframes will have some common index levels.

### Suggested

```
import re
import pandas as pd


# Based on https://aviationweather.gov/taf/decoder#Forecast
TAF_PATTERN = re.compile(
    r'''(?x)  # verbose
    ^\s*                  # beginning, strip whitespace
    (?P<group>[A-Z]+)?    # time group kind, greedy, optional
    (?:                   # non-capture: separator between group name and time
        (?<!FM)\s+        # spaces for every group except FM
    )?
    (?P<time>\d\S+)       # group time, starting with any digit, greedy, mandatory
    (?:                   # non-capture: wind speed with separator, optional
        \s+               # at least one separator space
        (?P<wind>\S*KT)   # anything followed by knots, greedy
    )?
    (?:                   # non-capture: visibilitity with separator, optional
        \s+               # at least one separator space
        (?P<vis>          # visibility
            P?            # "more than"
            \d+           # distance figure
            (?:SM)?       # unit: 'statute miles' or implied metres
        )
    )?
    (?:                   # non-capture: weather with separator, optional
        \s+               # at least one separator space
        (?P<weather>
            (?:\+|-|VC)?  # intensity or proximity
            (?:           # weather fragments, mandatory, greedy
                \s*       # any spaces between weather fragments
                (?:
                    MI|BC|DR|BL|SH|TS|FZ|PR|     # Qualifier descriptor
                    DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|  # Precipitation
                    BR|FG|FU|DU|SA|HZ|PY|VA|     # Obscuration
                    PO|SQ|FC|\+FC|SS|DS          # "Other"
                )
            )+
        )
    )?
    (?P<clouds>       # cloud measurements, optional
        (?:           # non-capture: clouds, mandatory, greedy, multiple included
            \s+       # at least one separator space
            (?:       # cloud density measured in "octals" (eighths)
                VV|NSC|SKC|NCD|CLR|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC
            )
            \d*          # observation altitude in hundreds of feet
            (?:CB|TCU)?  # clouds, optional, cumulonimbus or towering cumulus
        )+
    )?
    # Don't specify the rest, and don't match on the end. This may exclude
    # wind shear, probability, etc.
    '''
)

CLOUD_PATTERN = re.compile(
    r'''(?x)  # verbose
    (?P<density>   # cloud density measured in "octals" (eighths)
        VV|NSC|SKC|NCD|CLR|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC
    )
    (?P<altitude>  # observation altitude in hundreds of feet, greedy, optional
        \d+
    )?
    (?P<kind>      # cloud kind, cumulonimbus or towering cumulus, optional
        CB|TCU
    )?
    '''
)


def get_sky_condition(taf: str) -> tuple[
    pd.DataFrame,  # Groups
    pd.DataFrame,  # Clouds
]:
    station, origin_time, body = taf.split(maxsplit=2)
    lines = pd.Series(body.splitlines())
    df: pd.DataFrame = lines.str.extract(TAF_PATTERN)

    df['station'] = station
    df['origin_time'] = origin_time
    df.set_index(['station', 'origin_time', 'group', 'time'], inplace=True)

    clouds: pd.DataFrame = df.clouds.str.extractall(CLOUD_PATTERN)
    clouds['altitude'] = clouds.altitude.astype(int) * 100
    clouds = clouds.droplevel('match').set_index('altitude', append=True)

    df.drop(columns=['clouds'], inplace=True)

    return df, clouds


def test() -> None:
    taf = """
KGCC 282320Z    2900/2924  09010KT P6SM -SHRA                   BKN070    OVC250
     FM290300              24011KT P6SM                                   OVC040
     TEMPO      2903/2906           4SM -SHRA     FEW010 FEW015 BKN020TCU OVC025
     FM291000              18009KT  3SM -TSRA BR                          OVC004CB
     FM291900           31022G33KT  6SM -SHRA                             OVC011
     TEMPO      2903/2906          5000  TSRA
"""

    group_df, cloud_df = get_sky_condition(taf)
    print('Groups:')
    print(group_df)
    print('Clouds:')
    print(cloud_df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

### Output

```
Groups:
                                           wind   vis   weather
station origin_time group time                                 
KGCC    282320Z     NaN   2900/2924     09010KT  P6SM     -SHRA
                    FM    290300        24011KT  P6SM       NaN
                    TEMPO 2903/2906         NaN   4SM     -SHRA
                    FM    291000        18009KT   3SM  -TSRA BR
                          291900     31022G33KT   6SM     -SHRA
                    TEMPO 2903/2906         NaN  5000      TSRA
Clouds:
                                             density kind
station origin_time group time      altitude             
KGCC    282320Z     NaN   2900/2924 7000         BKN  NaN
                                    25000        OVC  NaN
                    FM    290300    4000         OVC  NaN
                    TEMPO 2903/2906 1000         FEW  NaN
                                    1500         FEW  NaN
                                    2000         BKN  TCU
                                    2500         OVC  NaN
                    FM    291000    400          OVC   CB
                          291900    1100         OVC  NaN
```

Comment: On mobile at the moment.  What I’m working towards is representing a taf as DataFrame and the observed condition as a Series. Converting times strings to time objects and replacing string values with numeric ones.  To then get the delta from a forecast and an observed condition. To which I apply a inversely proportional % of the time delta.

Comment: That's quite fine but I consider it out of scope for the current question.

Comment: Understood.  I do have a question, why do you prefer to initialize with a DataFrame rather than Series

Comment: Good catch; that should be a `Series`